# AWS-EMR: Where is log file?

Tags: amazon-web-services

I am using EMR to run spark job through yarn. The job failed but I cannot find where EMR log the exception, I can see the traceback on the master node screen output as below. There should be a more detailed log file which shows what causes the exception but I cannot find where it is. I looked at the hdfs://var/log/spark/app/application_xxx which doesn't show any error. Here is how I submit the application:

```
spark-submit --deploy-mode cluster --master yarn --num-executors 1 --executor-cores 2 --executor-memory 5g word2vec_app.py hdfs:///test/r8_no_sto.txt
```

Here is the screen output on the master node:

```
Exception in thread "main" org.apache.spark.SparkException: Application application_1488419676573_0005 finished with failed status
    at org.apache.spark.deploy.yarn.Client.run(Client.scala:1167)
    at org.apache.spark.deploy.yarn.Client$.main(Client.scala:1213)
    at org.apache.spark.deploy.yarn.Client.main(Client.scala)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit$.org$apache$spark$deploy$SparkSubmit$$runMain(SparkSubmit.scala:738)
    at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit$.doRunMain$1(SparkSubmit.scala:187)
    at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit$.submit(SparkSubmit.scala:212)
    at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit$.main(SparkSubmit.scala:126)
    at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit.main(SparkSubmit.scala)
```

Comment: There will be a folder in your s3. While configuration EMR I think we have the option to set log dir. BY default it is stored in s3 . Path is s3://aws-logs-[ACCOUNT_NUMBER]-[AVAILABILITY_ZONE]/elasticmapreduce/

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The stdout/stderr of the node can be found at /mnt/var/log/hadoop-yarn/containers/application in each node.

Answer (score 1):

There will be a folder in your s3. While configuration EMR I think we have the option to set log dir. Path is s3://aws-logs-[ACCOUNT_NUMBER]-[AVAILABILITY_ZONE]/elasticma‌​preduce/

Comment: I did not check the option to save it on S3. Will it still be logged on the hdfs or on the nodes?

Comment: @Manish Verma bro you know how to store the custom logs to s3 bucket i'm able to check the system log to the s3 bucket but i have one application log file which contains the code related logs which i'm not able to find on s3 bucket please ping me if you have any answer related to this...thnx in advance